# About Shem's age

Tags: genesis

according to my count it appears that Shem lived, and most likely preached and taught up to and until Isaac's 35th year of life. Can that be confirmed by use of hermeneutic method and source criticism?

Comment: Many commentators have done the math, like you, and deduced the same.  What specific problem or question does this present for you that hermeneutics or source criticism might help answer?  What do you want confirmed?  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: That hermeneutics have no place in discussion of what the Bible says. It is either true or false. What is meant by what is written is all that is left to discuss. Now exegesis is valuable in the case of Hebrew and greek Syntax and Grammar. The Bible claims to be a collection of writings BY GOD. There is no room for philosophical interpretation. One must either ask the Author for insight or one denies the very authenticity of it. That is why this subset of Stack exchange sux so bad.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I did a generation by generation analysis of the key figures in *Genesis* and arrived at a similar answer. [Genesis 11:10](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-11/) says Shem was 100 years old when he begat Arphaxad. Continuing with the following generations: Arphaxad begat Salah when he was 35 years old (11:12); Salah begat Eber when he was 30 years old (11:14); Eber begat Peleg when he was 34 years old (11:16); Peleg begat Reu when he was 30 years old (11:18); Reu begat Serug when he was 32 years old (11:20); Serug begat Nahor when he was 30 years old (11:22); Nahor begat Terah when he was 29 years old (11:24); Terah begat Abram (Abraham) when he was 70 years old (11:26); Abraham begat Isaac when he was 100 years old ([21:5](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-21/)). These generations total 490 years from the birth of Shem to the birth of Isaac. Genesis 11:11 tells us that Shem lived 500 years after Arphaxad was born, giving him a total lifespan of 600 years: he lived 10 years after Isaac was born.

Even more surprising is that the same calculations show Noah and all his direct descendants were still alive until Abraham was 60 years old, yet Abraham had apparently never heard of them and, in spite of them being able to pass on their personal knowledge of God, the whole world knew nothing of God when Abraham was young.

The answer to this puzzle would be that Noah and Shem belonged to a separate tradition than did Abraham, although both traditions were preserved in the same written source. Notice the brevity of references to Arphaxad, Salah, Eber, Peleg, Reu, Serug and Nahor. And notice also how they all had their firstborn boys at around 30 years, quite unlike the generations that went before and the generations that came after. They appear to be 'fillers' inserted purely to create some elapsed time between Noah and Terah. Shem's lifespan appears to be quite arbitrary, having his firstborn at just 100 years and then living just 500 more years.

Comment: The other problem (of course) is that the numbers for the years in the Masoretic version of the Hebrew Bible are radically different from those in the Septuagint, and also from those in the Samaritan Pentateuch.

Comment: You soundlike you think the bible is a history book written for the entertainment of children to be retold when getting ready for bed. I think that Shem lived at least 500 years after the flood, and lived and Taught amongst his Kinfolk Like Abram, and How he learned to hear God talking to him, long enough to hear him tell him to get out of the land of his father in Ur. Shem would have been considered a "Light" amongst his people and the unbelieving and/or ignorant would have taken to calling the Sun the Fire of Shem, because his Word was God's. Hence the semetic name for the Sun "Shemash".

Comment: And I wouldn't put too much authority by the LXX. I would advise you to use it for reference only, the masoretic Hebrew used by the Scholars of the KJV is better for original expression. The Samaritan Pentateuch is only good for showing that they had any scripture at all, not for accuracy.

Comment: This answer is not supported by any evidence and contains many assumptions, how do we know that Abraham had never heard of Noah?

Comment: @reidh fdb is right - for completeness I could have mentioned differences in the LXX and Samaritan manuscripts.  We do not presume that the Masoretic text should always be the only version considered.  Reference to other versions is at times relevant in a hermeneutics discussion.

Comment: @JonathanChell You mean that not one sentence in the answer is supported by evidence, even though I cited verse after verse from Genesis, or do you mean that I made assumptions when, for example, I added together the lengths of each generation? Or was that just hyperbole in your comment?  As for Abraham, if he knew Noah why did Noah not tell him anything about God?

Comment: @Dick Harfield you're being a bit harsh on Jonathan Chell's comment. Your first paragraph is fine and supported.  But your conclusions in the next two are clearly what he is referring to.  There are many assumptions and no citations in your second two paragraphs.  You cannot deny that. He never said anything about not one sentence, he said your answer. The work in the first paragraph is not an answer, it is evidence that should support your conclusions. The only hyperbole here was yours. If you have support for your other comments then please edit and and them but let's be civil.

Comment: @Dick Harfield I tend to agree with your estimation of Shem's total life span. I think the LXX is to the Masoretic as is the KJV. If Shem truly existed during Abram's life, he ( Abram ) would have certainly heard of, if not from, him. The custom amongst the semites to quote their lineage would have certainly familiarized him with Shem. My theory that the sun was named Shemash due to Shem's output, is just a notion. To me, it seems that Shem could have known of Melchizedek, as he (Melchizedek) had no beginning nor end.(heb 7:3)&(Psalms 110:4)

Comment: @DickHarfield's answer responds appropriately to the OP's question, including biblical evidence and source criticism. +1